# Dropdown Information Boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create dropdown menus that contain information similar to that of what this website has down in their main body.

http://www.alexanderresearch.com.au/index.php?option=com_moofaq&Itemid=3

I would like the functionality to be similar to that of these information boxes, i would like some help in pointing me in the right direction to be able to create this for my website. Any help would be appreciate, Thankyou in  advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The design pattern you are referring to is called an Accordion.

Since your question is tagged jQuery, I assume you're using it, so you could add a script from jQuery UI here:

http://jqueryui.com/accordion/

Let me know if you need help integrating it.

Comment: Thankyou thats exactly what is was looking for, is it possible for this to be achieved in CSS? And yes I am using jQuery although it would be better for me to use CSS, Cheers.

Comment: I don't think its possible to do it purely with CSS. You could possibly do it with CSS3 transitions, but even then you would need javascript to add classes to the elements to trigger the animation.

Comment: I ended up doing most of it with CSS3 transitions, but i needed the javascript file too. It's all working now, thankyou for your help!

Comment: No worries! If you're satisfied with me answer, don't forget to tick accept :)

Answer (score 1):

It is an accordion menu. You can find it here. 
http://jqueryui.com/accordion/#hoverintent